# Unit Test can't find injected dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

My prject uses spring-boot 2.1.6.

I trying to test the following code:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {

    @Autowired
    private MyClient client;

    @Value("${api.bah.url}")
    private String url;

    public SaidaPadrao listarCnpj(DtoCnpjRequest dtoRequest) {
        log.debug("Sending request to url=" + url);
        return client.listarCnpjConvivencia(dtoRequest);
    }
}
```

(Notice that I simplify the code a bit.)

In my tests, I trying to do like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class )
public class AleloConvivenciaComponentTest {

    @Autowired
    @Spy
    private MyComponent comp;

    @Test
    public void testHML() {

        var dtoRequest = // ...

        SaidaPadrao listarCnpjs = comp.listarCnpj(dtoRequest);

        // ...
    }
```

Problems I got:

When using `@Autowired` (without the `@Spy`) to load `MyComponent comp` I get NullPointer on comp in my unit test.
When using `@Autowired` and `@Spy` I manage to run the test on `comp.listarCnpj`.

But then, the test fails inside the `comp.listarCnpj` method with a NullPointer at client.listarCnpjConvivencia`

What am I missing? I want to run this method completly, no mocks in this case.

Bonus question: `${api.bah.url}` is in default `application.yml` file but it seems to not load for some reason. The value is always null. I simplify the code but this config is used inside `client.listarCnpjConvivencia`. This config file shouldn't be loaded by default on tests?

Comment: about the bonus question I think you should ask it as different question because it deserve its own answer

Comment: Ok, I posted in the same question 'cause I thought it was releated.

Answer (score 0):

Unit test run in a separate context than Spring Boot application that you run normally, it all run and managed by JUnit framework.

You can learn more about JUnit [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) it describes how the framework works it wonders.

By the code you provided looks like you want to get the object instantiated by the Spring Framework but you only using MockitoJUnitRunner which will only provide mocking capabilities, you should use SpringRunner to tackle this task and depends on your need whether you need the whole spring context or not you can either use @SpringBootTest annotation for that purposes.

I suggest you check this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing) as it describe detailed information and examples about how you can achieve this.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer! It makes total sens now for me. I tryed adding `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@SpringBootTest` but got a different error now, `IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` - `Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.client.CommonsClientAutoConfiguration$DiscoveryLoadBalancerConfiguration.discoveryCompositeHealthContributor`
Any tips?

Comment: The error seems to be `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/CompositeHealthContributor` witch makes no sens at all to me. :S

Comment: can you paste the updated code and the whole error log on the question?